# discordjs v13 voice join channel

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

I hve a big issue. I have coded a music bot in nodejs. I have an array with bot data (example: bot name, id, channel id, ect.) and I create a `Discord.Client` for every bot in a `for`.

In `on('ready')` I create the callbacks (sending an embeded message with reaction buttons in the text channel. And when a user click on play, pause or whatever, i run a code. All fine.

When user click on the play button, the bot should connect to the voice channel from user, and play an audio. Works fine.

But now my problem:

With one bot, all works without any issues. But when I have 2 bots, and the player click on play, the correct bot comes to the channel. But when user change the channel, and play the another bot, then the old one come. I logged with `console.log()` and the bot ids (ex. `bot.client.user.id`) give the correct result. But why the old bot connect?

I am using the discordjs/voice library. And I don't know, how I can pass the method, which client should be connect... from where the method takes the client?

That's my join method

```
function playMusic(bot, botClient, channel, guildID, adapterCreator) {
    try {
        console.log("BOT ID: " + bot.id);
        console.log("BOT USER ID: " + botClient.user.id);

        let vc = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: channel.id,
            guildId: guildID,
            adapterCreator: adapterCreator
        });

        let resource = createAudioResource(createReadStream('resources/audio.mp3'), {
            inlineVolume : true
        });

        //resource.volume.setVolume(0.2);

        var player = createAudioPlayer();

        vc.subscribe(player);
        player.play(resource);

        return player;
    } catch(ex) {
        console.log(ex);

        return undefined;
    }
}
```

Comment: so my problem is, how I can control WHICH client should be connect to a voice channel.

Comment: How are you calling `playMusic`? Where are you getting `adapterCreator` from? From looking at the source of @discordjs/voice, `adapterCreator` is the thing that links the Discord.js client to the @discordjs/voice library.

Comment: Also it looks like @discordjs/voice reuses voice connections from the same guild, no matter what client/bot it's for. Once you've got the `adapterCreator` thing sorted (it should come from a VC from the client you want to use to join the VC), try using `group: 'a unique group name for each bot'` in `joinVoiceChannel`.